# Why Does TaskList.exe Never End When Redirecting Standard Output?

Tags: c#, windows, process, freeze, tasklist

When I attempt to run tasklist.exe with the Process class and set RedirectStandardOutput to true, the process never ends.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunProcess("tasklist.exe");
    }

    private static void RunProcess(string command)
    {
        var process = new Process()
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = command,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            }
        };

        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

If I set RedirectStandardOutput to false, the process does end!!!

Why does the tasklist.exe Process never end?  I am using Windows 7 and .net framework 4.5.2.

I found out that when I forcefully close tasklist.exe, there is exactly 4096 bytes written to standard output every time!  Is there some kind of character buffer that I need to increase in size?

Comment: You don't read the output..

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: I can easily add these two line after the WaitForExit, but it will never gets executed:         var response = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(response);

Comment: Indeed. The buffer is full, so writes to stdout from the process will block. Read the buffer to allow the process to proceed.

Comment: Also, if I use the OutputDataReceived event, it never gets called!

Comment: The buffer fills up, so tasklist.exe blocks waiting for you read it, before it can finish writing.

Comment: You need to read *before* WaitForExit. See discussion on deadlocks here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx

Comment: I'll try it.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, OutputDataReceived is for use with BeginOutputReadLine - the asynchronous API.

Comment: Indeed. If you `ReadToEnd`, that is the end of the process. If you then `WaitForExit`, it will effectively be redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `RedirectStandardOutput = true` add this line to your code:

```
process.Start();

// To avoid deadlocks, always read the output stream first and then wait.
string out = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I think you mean to use StandardOutput instead of StandardError, but yes this works!

Comment: Thank you LVBen ;)