# Retrieving the actual user account that started a process

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve the user account under which a process has been started. So far i have not found any answers that retrieve the **good** information. All of them return the `string` of the username which is not the account. I have tried WMI and Diagnostic all with the same results which are half correct.

Let's say i start notepad twice.

- First one i open it with the account : \MyDomain\Franck
- Second on i open it with the account : \MyComputer\Franck

Then use either WMI or Diagnostics and both return username "Franck" and i have not way to know if it's running under the local user or the domain one.

One way could be to use Diagnostics

```
var procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").ToList();
var notepad1 = procs[0].StartInfo.Environment["Username"];
var notepad2 = procs[1].StartInfo.Environment["Username"];
```

Both return `Franck` but one is the domain account and the other is the local.

Comment: Are you starting these processes in code, or looking at existing running processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tasklist /v` gives the relevant info that you are interested in, i.e., the user name with the domain name.

The [official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist) documentation does not show any sample outputs.

> tasklist
>
> Displays a list of currently running processes on the local computer or on a remote computer.
>
> /v Displays verbose task information in the output.

You can use it together with `/fo csv` option to get the result and parse it.

This [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/893372/how-can-i-see-which-user-accounts-are-running-which-processes-in-windows-8-1) from SuperUser has screen shots showing the output.

You can run this command as a separate process from your application similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41273181/why-does-tasklist-exe-never-end-when-redirecting-standard-output), but passing the other [parameters](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo).

Comment: This is perfect. It does show the real user running the process.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the name of the domain that contains the user's account, then you're looking for [UserDomain Environment Variable](http://environmentvariables.org/UserDomain)

If you want  which domain controller authenticated the client's logon request, then you're looking for [LogonServer Environment Variable](http://environmentvariables.org/LogonServer)

```
var procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad").
var userDomain = procs[0].StartInfo.Environment["UserDomain"];
var logonServer = procs[0].StartInfo.Environment["LogonServer"];
```

Values on my windows machine (local user):

```
userDomain: "LAPTOP-DDK137L8"
logonServer: "\\LAPTOP-DDK137L8"
```

So from this you should be able to determine if it's running under the local user or the domain one.

Comment: It does not work either. Both process return the exact same values for all `Username`, `UserDomain` and `LoginServer` which are "Franck", "MyDomain", "MyDomainController"

Comment: Are you running both of them on the same machine? if yes then you will get same values I guess.
Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710355/check-if-user-is-a-domain-user-or-local-user

Comment: Both are on the same machine. same session on a user logged as domain. ill check the link later